# gulp protractor sets argv.baseur

Tags: gulp, protractor

```
gulp.task(
    'protractor', function () { console.log("xx4");

        var configObj = {
            configFile: config.test + 'protractor.conf.js'
        };
        configObj['args'] =[];//to be able to add multiple parameters

        if (argv.suite) {
            configObj['args'].push (
                '--suite',
                argv.suite
            );
        }

        if (argv.env) {
            configObj['args'].push (
                '--env',
                argv.env
            );
        }

            argv.baseUrl = produrl;
            console.log("devurl",produrl);


        configObj['args'].push (
            '--baseUrl',
            argv.baseUrl
        );
        console.log("argv.baseUrl",argv.baseUrl);
        return gulp.src([])
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(protractor(configObj))
            .on(
                'error', function () {
                    gutil.log('E2E Tests failed');
                    process.exit(1);
                }
            );
    }
);

var qaurl = require('./env-config/qa-baseurl');
var produrl = require('./env-config/prod-baseurl');
var localurl = require('./env-config/local-baseurl');


gulp.task('qa', function () {

    console.log("argv.baseUrl",argv.baseUrl);
});

gulp.task('local', function () {
    console.log("xx3");
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
});
```

when  i run

```
gulp protractor
```

or

gulp protractor qa

it should make argv.baseurl for qa url and it should push to configobj. but configobj is in protractor.

```
 ReferenceError: configObj is not defined
```

this is erro.r.

```
gulp.task(
    'protractor', ['env'],function () { console.log("xx4");
```

i can do something like this but it wont push again. Also i cant get qa or local to parameter to put firstly task?

for that

```
  gulp.task(
        'protractor', ['env']
```

i mean here, first go to env (env means qa or prod or local)

when i run from

gulp protractor local

how i can get local to that env?

How can i make it push and so that i can use in protractor

this is localurl

```
module.exports = "localhost:8080";
```

only url

i cam use setbaseurl task [setbaseurl] but how wiil i get local in

gulp protractor local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for pushing data in array:

```
var configObj = {'configFile': 'protractor.conf.js',
       'arg':''};
configObj['arg'] = [];
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
    configObj['arg'].push('value of i::' + i);
}
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
Object {configFile: "protractor.conf.js", arg: Array[5]}

where arg is:
0:"value of i::0"
1:"value of i::1"
2:"value of i::2"
3:"value of i::3"
4:"value of i::4"
```

For gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var taskName = '';
gulp.task(
    'protractor', function () {
        taskName = process.argv[3]; 
    }, taskName.toString());

gulp.task('qa', function () {
    console.log("qa task executing");
});

gulp.task('local', function () {
    console.log("local task executing");
});
```

command used:

```
gulp protractor qa
```

Output on console:

```
$ gulp protractor qa
[13:18:52] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\sample file\gulpfile.js
[13:18:52] Starting 'protractor'...
[13:18:52] Finished 'protractor' after 55 μs
[13:18:52] Starting 'qa'...
qa task executing
[13:18:52] Finished 'qa' after 21 μs
```

If you want to use this configObj in conf.js file then in the args section, pass `['--params.configObj', configObj]`
where `"--params.configObj"` is defined in conf.js

```
params: {
        configObj: ''
        }
```

To add self reference you can use like:

```
configObj['--params.configObj'] = configObj;
```